# Is content within code HTML tags XSS vulnerable?

Tags: html, codeigniter, xss

I am using Codeingiter, I see that the `xss_clean()` is replacing the tab characters with a single space character. This is breaking the contents that are later displayed inside `<pre><code></code></pre>` tags.

Can XSS attack string inside `<code>` HTML tag be of any problem?

If yes, is there a way to retain the tabs in such a situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, XSS attacks within the `<code>` element are still a problem. To get around this, you should escape your code within the `<code>` block. e.g.

```
<pre><code>&lt;p%gt;this is an example paragraph in code&lt;/p&gt;</code></pre>
```

Which will display as:

```
<p>this is an example paragraph in code</p>
```

Comment: So in my case I should use `&#09;` for showing a tab character inside the `<pre><code></code></pre>`. 'K got it thanks! :)