# Avoid XSS with an HTML tag like <pre>

Tags: html, tags, xss, pre

I have a simple webpage that takes query items and crafts them in to the page.
Example URL:

```
http://quir.li/player.html?media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D0VqTwnAuHws
```

The page then has the URL displayed somewhere in the page:

```
<span id="sourceUrlDisplay">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VqTwnAuHws</span>
```

I feel that this makes the page vulnerable to XSS in case the page gets loaded with an URL containing something similar to

```
http://quir.li/player.html?media=<script>alert('test')</script>
```

I have found, that rendering the URL into a `<pre>` tag does not help. **Is there a simple solution to this, like an HTML tag whose content really is not interpreted but just printed out?**

*Note*: This question is somewhat [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409184/is-content-within-code-html-tags-xss-vulnerable), but more general.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the common defenses against XSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129899/what-are-the-common-defenses-against-xss)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no such tag in HTML that would prevent XSS attacks, and it's impossible to make one. Let's assume that there was such a tag, say, `<safe>`. The attacker would only need to close it: `</safe><script> malicious code </script><safe>`.

The way to stop XSS in this specific case would be to escape special characters to their URL encoding counterparts, so that `http://quir.li/player.html?media=<script>alert('test')</script>` becomes  `http://quir.li/player.html?media=%3Cscript%3Ealert('test')%3C%2Fscript%3E`.

Comment: You are right about the closing tag. Obvious, once you told me now! Many thanks, accepted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape special characters of HTML to remove their special meaning. For example, in PHP, [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function is intended for such escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth mentioning that there actually are 2 (deprecated) HTML tags that do exactly what you're looking for: [`<xmp>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp) and [`<listing>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/listing). Any HTML inside these tags will be shown as text in most browsers.

The keyword here being: most. The tags have been deprecated since HTML 3.2 and while it seems to still be supported by Chrome and Firefox (and possibly more browsers), who knows when they will be completely removed. On top of that, it is not impossible that some browsers may have implemented it incorrectly.

In the end, you're still better off escaping the HTML as the other answers say.